# Expandable base class methods?

Tags: c++, templates

(I am not sure if this falls under templates or virtual functions or some of both).

Suppose we have a base class (say tuple2) with only two values x,y.
This base class has a method called "norm" that operates on x,y such as (sqrt(x*x+y*y)).

Now we want to extend this class such that:

```
struct tuple2
{
   double x,y;
   double norm ()                       {return sqrt(x*x+y*y);}
   double dotProd (const tuple2& other) {return other.x*x+other.y*y;}
}

struct tuple3:public tuple2
{
   double z;
}
```

tuple3 adds a single variable.

Is it possible to define the base class method such that it can handle x,y, and z combined without overloading ?

The functions are not identical, but have identical **pattern**. I guess I am looking for some kind of template that expands on number of variables, not just type ?

Comment: How about using a `vector` to pass an arbitrary number of numbers to `dotProd`? You could make it an `initializer_list` if you do not like copies and dynamic memory.

Comment: Limited to this tuple case, it would help to store the member variables in a container. [variadic templates](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) may help, but I guess it becomes complex rather quickly.

Comment: @nwp: Using a vector adds a 12byte overhead. Taking the example literally we might as well just define a tuple3 with three doubles and use it for everything. No ?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a free function. You can [read an article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197?pgno=1) that reasons that free functions are generally to be preferred to member functions.

```
double dotProd(const tuple2 &t1, const tuple2 &t2){
    return t1.x * t2.x + t1.y * t2.y;
}

double dotProd(const tuple3 &t1, const tuple3 &t2){
    return t1.x * t2.x + t1.y * t2.y + t1.z * t2.z;
}
```

It is easy to write, easy to understand, easy to extend and performs very well.

I have not had much success extending classes with inheritance in C++ and would not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

The abstraction can be obtained by Inheritance and by using templates. But how I will decide depends on following rules.
If the generalized class is to be used by objects having operations in common do use templates
if both attributes and operations are common (similar objects) do preffer Inheritance.

Is it possible to define the base class method such that it can handle x,y, and z combined without overloading ?

Simply No!!!
 If functions have identical pattern, I will prefer Template specialization.

Note: these are my views i would really appreciate someone who can correct these if they are not correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to take a look at this :

http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/c++_practical_programming/c++_practical_programming_106.html

With your example, it would be :

```
template <size_t N>
struct tuple
{
    std::array<double, N> elements;
    double norm()
    {
        double n(0.);
        for ( std::size_t i(0) ; i < N ; ++i )
            n += std::pow(elements[i], 2.);
        return std::pow(n, 0.5);
    }
};
```

I understand your problem with dot and other specific functions... You have to choose whether the function can be declared inside or not the class. If you want to put a specific function inside (cross product works only with N == 3), use enable_if like this :

```
template<bool B, typename T = void>
using Enable_if = typename std::enable_if<B, T>::type;

template <size_t N>
struct tuple
{
    std::array<double, N> elements;
    double norm()
    {
        double n(0.);
        for ( std::size_t i(0) ; i < N ; ++i )
            n += std::pow(elements[i], 2.);
        return std::pow(n, 0.5);
    }
    template<class THIS = tuple<N>,
         typename = Enable_if<std::is_same<THIS, tuple<3>>::value>>
    tuple<3> getCrossProduct(const tuple<3>& other);
};

template <std::size_t N>
template<class THIS, typename>
tuple<3> tuple<N>::getCrossProduct(const tuple<3>& other)
{/*...*/}
```

You can do many things with enable if inside a class, except defining two versions (with different N) of the same function that take the same argument list.

I hope it would be helpful for your needs.